# When to use Ascyntask and when to you use Service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am in doubt when to use `AsyncTask` and when to use `Service`. As of now I understand `AsyncTask` is used if GUI update is required service can be used more complex interaction using `Binder` as well as can be used for interaction with different process

Comment: Asynctask is meant to handle Network Request which you would like to run in the background and not black your UI thread. On the other hand Services are for the jobs you want to do without frequent user interaction like playing songs

Answer (score 0):

**From AsyncTask  docs -**

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

**From Service docs -**

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

Now coming to what OP asked--

```
When to use AsyncTask?
```

Android implements single thread model and whenever an android application is launched, a thread is created. Assuming we are doing network operation on a button click in our application. On button click a request would be made to the server and response will be awaited. Due to single thread model of android, till the time response is awaited our screen is non-responsive. So we should avoid performing long running operations on the UI thread. This includes file and network access.

To overcome this we can create new thread and implement run method to perform this network call, so UI remains responsive.

But since Android follows single thread model and Android UI toolkit is not thread safe, so if there is a need to make some change to the UI based on the result of the operation performed, then this approach may lead some issues.

So the Android framework has given a very good pattern which is enveloped into AsyncTask.

```
When to use Service?
```

We can use it for two main reasons -

- When we need to say Android that our application is doing some
  important things in background and should not be killed. To achieve
  this we can run Service as foreground via startForeground method.
- When we need to provide some functionality of our app to the other
  app. This can be done via exporting service in manifest file That's
  all. If you don't need to achieve one of these goals - you don't need
  Service at all.

**UPDATE:**

**AsyncTask** should ideally be used for operations that take few seconds. Some tasks keep the thread running for long time so in that case it is recommended to use java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

**Service** is used more for something that should happen on an interval or keep running/checking for something when there is no UI shown.

Comment: This is what is in android tutorial. Please clarify on what circumstances you will write a Ascyntask and what circumstances you will use service both does the work in baground

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AsyncTasks are linked to the Context they where launched from: If you launch an AsyncTask from an Activity, for example, and then want to finish this Activity, it will only finish when the AsyncTask finishes.
On the other hand, once the service is launched, it will do its job, without depend on any Context.

I think this is useful when you want to launch a network job during the Splash Screen, for example, without taking care of the end of your request: You'll launch your service, letting it do its job on his side and, on the other side, launch your Activity, without taking care of the result...

A Service is also useful for tasks that are going to be repeated many times and for tasks you want to continue during the context of your Application: a media player for example.

Comment: An AsyncTaask will be used in an activity or a fragment to make heavy work without freeze UI. A Service will be working in its own Thread and make any work you want during its lifetime: Play a music, refresh some data every XX seconds...